# PHP 7 "The ASP tags <%, %>, <%=" are deprecated

Tags: backbone.js, php-7

Per the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

I'm trying to learn some various MVC's and frameworks (namely Backbone.js at the moment) and the pages the frameworks use are .html files and a code snippet would be listed as:
    <%- title %>
(Source: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone/index.html)

Does this mean the frameworks won't work if my server has PHP 7? I realize I could go ahead and just try it this individual time but I'm wondering...in general...does PHP 7 think the <% tags are ASP only and such not allow them?

Comment: I wanted to confirm that in my VPS server all of the backbone.js code that is within (and including)`<% %>` is spat out as plain text using php7 when rendered on index.php. However, when rendered on index.html it displays as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backbone should work without any problem with PHP, see [example](https://foysalmamun.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/practice-backbone-js-with-php-example-1/), because the code is wrapped is a script tag.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-hello-backbone">
    <%= message %>
</script>
```

In case that you still encounter problems try to use Mustache.js and display the text using {{}}

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-hello-backbone">
       {{message }}
</script>
```

Comment: Underscore has the option to change `<%` to something else, like `{{}}`

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the information. I was a bit nervous as I'm learning multiple new things at once.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around. Dependent on the configuration, PHP 5 might think `<%- title %>` is PHP code (equivalent to `<?php - title ?>` which it is obviously not. PHP 7 on the other hand won't ever do anything with these tags, which is the behavior you want.